# Get Attendee details from the scanned Attendee badge's QR Code or Barcode

Tags: barcode, qr-code, eventbrite

Developing an ios application to get the Eventbrite events attendees details from the scanned attendee badge's QR Code or Barcode. From the Api documentation, I noticed that using '[Event Attendees’ Detail](http://developer.eventbrite.com/docs/event-attendees-details/)' Api method we can fetch the attendee's detail. My query is how will I get the 'Event ID' and and the 'Attendee ID' from the scanned data of badge's QR code or barcode.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

After researching Eventbrite API documentation I conclude:

- Internal structure of **Attendees Barcodes** field `barcode` (string) is undefined
- Eventbrite API lacks endpoints supporting query by `barcode` value

Google Groups **Eventbrite Developers**:

1. 2019-Oct https://groups.google.com/g/eventbrite-api/c/KlN1dGJztbU/m/EFywMQUIAgAJ

   - Dave (user developer)

     - makes **Attendee** query by `barcode` request and
     - shares `barcode` composition observations.
   - Jacob (Evenbrite Developer Support) confirms both

     - `barcode` query unsupported and
     - `barcode` composition observation.
2. 2020-Dec https://groups.google.com/g/eventbrite-api/c/qFxV6X2ODXU/m/NDYFrFRnAAAJ

   - Natalie Blikslager (Evenbrite Developer Support) confirms `barcode` query unsupported
3. 2018-Jul https://groups.google.com/g/eventbrite-api/c/tCmtnZEzSPw/m/tlfR-F8ZAgAJ

   - Nathan (Evenbrite Developer Support) confirms `barcode` query unsupported

Dave's Barcode Observations: XXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYZZZ

- first ten digits is `order_id`
- next ten digits is `attendee_id`
- last three digits are "001"

Eventbrite API fails to establish `barcode` contract sufficient for reliable query by `barcode` implementation.  I agree with Dave, list all attendees by event is only method not requiring prior knowledge of `barcode` composition.

Assuming `barcode` composition remains stable:

1. Dave's **Retrieve Attendee** by `event_id` and `attendee_id` is best
2. **Retrieve Order** by `order_id` with `attendees` expansion is good

Prior **Attendee** retrieval to local database with bulk query on-demand or Webhook makes direct `barcode` value query possible.